# Google Chrome extension error. Could not establish connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. Manifest v3

background script

```
import refresh from "virtual:reload-on-update-in-background-script";
refresh("pages/background");

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id as number, {
      message: "connection",
    });
  });
});
```

content script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
  if (request.message === "connection") {
    setStorageData(url, reports);
  }
});
```

Help to remove the error, it does not affect the extension, but still.

Comment: Did you add required permissions to manifest.json?
You need **tabs** and **activeTab** permissions.

Comment: Also,
>The Tabs API not only offers features for manipulating and managing tabs, but can also detect the language of the tab, take a screenshot, and communicate with a tab's content scripts.

`chrome.tabs` can only be used inside content script

Answer (score -1):

There might be an issue with the way you're setting up message passing between your background script and content script. Have you updated your manifest.json file as per v3 standards?

Also modify your background script (background.js) like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
      function: setStorageData,
      args: [{ message: "connection" }]
    });
  });
});

function setStorageData(request) {
  if (request.message === "connection") {
    // Do your content script logic here
  }
}
```

Also remove the `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener from your content script and put the logic inside the `setStorageData` function in your background script as shown above.

Comment: Just for sending message, `executeScript` is really dangerous. And isn't recommended for these types of scenariaos at all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).